# Which standardization method has to be used for creating more accurate density maps

Tags: statistics

I have a shapefile with 163 polygons which represents blocks of a metropolitan area. The attributes of the polygons are "Population, No of households, population with disability, etc..". Dividing the population by area will give population density. But how to normalize the population density ? I would like to create population density, household density, population with disability density maps relative to area. Do i have to use "z- score normalization" or "minimum - maximum normalization" to create more accurate maps.